# How do I generate a positive list of integers in jqwik and Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, jqwik

I have tried something like this, but seems like it's not working since I can see negatives in the generated list:

```
@Property
fun <testMethodName>(
  @ForAll @Size(min = 0, max = 1_500) 
  @Positive 
  @UniqueElements partials: List<@IntRange(min = 1, max = 10000) Int>
) = runTest { ... }
```

I wanted to generate the following:

1. An array of ints
2. a list with lenght between 0 to 1500
3. values of every elements should be unique
4. values of list elements must be between 1 to 10000

Comment: What is runTest doing? In a standard jqwik property Tests it wouldn’t be there, but you’d have a normal function body instead. Moreover, the Positive annotation has no effect in this position.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works using jqwik 1.7.2 on my machine:

```kotlin
import net.jqwik.api.ForAll
import net.jqwik.api.Property
import net.jqwik.api.constraints.Size
import net.jqwik.api.constraints.UniqueElements
import net.jqwik.kotlin.api.JqwikIntRange

class KotlinExperiments {
    @Property
    fun testMethodName(
        @ForAll @Size(min = 0, max = 1_500)
        @UniqueElements partials: List<@JqwikIntRange(min = 1, max = 10000) Int>
    ) {
        println(partials)
    }
}
```

`JqwikIntRange` is an alias for `net.jqwik.api.constraints.IntRange` since
the Kotlin library has its own `IntRange` class.

If this doesn't work for you, check if you've done the [necessary configuration for Kotlin](https://jqwik.net/docs/current/user-guide.html#build-configuration-for-kotlin)?